# Behavior when plugging USB

Tags: notifications, usb

When I plug in a USB stick or an external hard drive the system does absolutely nothing to notify me that this happened. The external device works perfectly fine, it's just that I don't get the classic little sound or pop-up telling me that it was connected.

I was wondering, is there a way to modify this behavior and make it so that the system allows me to chose something like "open in folder" ??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install a file manager that offers this feature, such as Nautilus. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1094669) for adding this feature to Pantheon-Files.

See also: [Will the developers add the option to automount external media & devices?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/will-the-developers-add-the-option-to-automount-external-media-devices/9463)